# Linear algebra with a linear model (Matlab)

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, regression

Given the equation

$$r = B + e(r\cos(\theta))$$

and the corresponding data:

$\theta: 0.88; 1.1; 1.42; 1.77; 2.14$ and $r:     3; 2.4; 1.65; 1.25; 1.01$

How do you input these data for matlab to solve for $B$ and $e$?

Comment: You know how to do a linear regression in MATLAB?

Comment: No, I do not. I don't understand the answer given at all.

Comment: You know how to solve a least-squares problem, don't you?

Comment: By hand. I don't see how that applies to this

Comment: Okay, I added a hint to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleve Moler's [*Numerical Computing with MATLAB*](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/index_ncm.html) has [this excellent chapter on how to do least squares](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/leastsquares.pdf); you can adapt any of the methods discussed there. To give you a few nudges on how to do your code: you have `r` as a dependent variable, and you can construct a new independent variable `rc=r.*cos(theta);`, where `r` and `theta` are appropriately constructed arrays. [You can use `[]` to form the columns of the matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/specialcharacters.html) required for the linear regression, and then [use `\`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) to get the least squares solution.

Or, there's [`polyfit()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyfit.html)...

---

OP seems to have some difficulty seeing how least squares applies here, so here's a hint on how to assemble the equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&r_1\cos\,\theta_1\\1&r_2\cos\,\theta_2\\1&r_3\cos\,\theta_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}B\\e\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r_1\\r_2\\r_3\end{pmatrix}$$